# Create, parse, manage XML file from a Java application exported as runnable .jar file

Tags: java, xml, jar

I have a problem in managing files from a Java program exported as runnable jar application.

To load the images of the application I have already used the syntax

`URL url = MainClass.class.getResource("/LoginOrRegister.png");`

And I have already configured the Build path of my project adding the folders which contains the files to the source, and it works fine.

My problem occurs with operations like the following:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
...
... (Here I create the whole XML structure)
...
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("users/familyName.xml"));
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Or

```
String userPath = "users/familyName.xml";
File file = new File(userPath);         

if (!file.exists()){
    JOptionPane jop = new JOptionPane();
    ......
}
```

By executing the program from Eclipse it works fine, you can register and the application creates new XML files in which after the login you can add, modify, and manage your data, so my question is:

Is there a way to create a runnable jar application that permits to do the same things? (Creating new file, loading data from file, storing data to file)

I know that for doing the DOM parsing of an existing XML file I can do

```
InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("blablab.xml");
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(is);
```

But I can do this only if I already have my XML file with all the data, I still don't know how to do all the other operation I need to do...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly in this line

```
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("users/familyName.xml"));
```

You are trying to load / create a file with a relative path, and I guess it's a file that will be created somewhere in your project tree,

Once You create a jar file it cannot be modified at least by it self, which means you can't create in run time a file inside your project tree which will be created inside your jar.

This file must be created outside of your project tree, something like this :

```
 StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("/opt/data/users/familyName.xml"));
```

Comment: Yes, the folders (like "users") in which I want to create the files and from which I want to load the files are outside the "src" folder, but still is not working

Comment: even if it's outside you need to put the absolute path of it, then check permissions you need to have read and write permissions on the containing directory